# Avoid silly inference for union types ( Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type...)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

So I have a variant of question that was asked before but somehow non of the answers help.
Here's the code:

```js
type ModelA = {
    type: 'a'
    method: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

type ModelB = {
    type: 'b'
    method: 'baz'
}

type Model = ModelA | ModelB

const dictionary = {
    a: {
        foo: () => 'foo',
        bar: () => 'bar'
    },
    b: {
        baz: () => 'baz'
    }
}

function getMethod(m: Model): Function {
    return dictionary[m.type][m.method] <--- error
}

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"foo" | "bar" | "baz"' can't be used to index type '{ foo: () => string; bar: () => string; } | { baz: () => string; }'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ foo: () => string; bar: () => string; } | { baz: () => string; }'.
```

If I use some silly type check like this:

```
function getMethod(m: Model) {
    if (m.type === 'a') {
        return dictionary[m.type][m.method]
    }
    return dictionary[m.type][m.method]
}
```

it works because that in both branches TS knows that it's safe to get the method.

I know this should be solved using generic but somehow I can't figure out.

Comment: pls share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian not sure what do you mean? Here's the playgroun where do error is visible:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwIJQLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AIbn6EC2EwAFomeQGZxzlQA+FAI0oAnGgF9cuYtHhJkAIUw5aBaWwE1CUBs1aDKAL3GTpsRCiWyU6flYWSAxnAB2AZ2BQEASwfAvLkRAlPC1KMhCtQk44MgAKAEpMAD4KaPIAGhVIoWE4xIwU8hzNQjFMrQFwrIrDPOT9IyyJCVx2AFdnX39nKABzRhhGFgQAJli6Mjt4sgAxDq6XZS1hRjbhHu8F50CAbToAOmkAXT39nWGj3BaAemuoABUACQBJAGUoAHUAeQAlAGl3vIAKr3KDPe7kd6ve5AgAKzwAIq15n5Fv1gINdAhXl5kMgQONJuZkIkIgQvOwoONDuBoBh6RRqKTqoQVsA1hsfKjtsIQKdjqdzohLloJMtVutPFzursDgKDkKEJcWkA

Answer (score 2):

In order to type it, you need to infer `dictionary` and each object property:

```js
type ModelA = {
    type: 'a'
    method: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

type ModelB = {
    type: 'b'
    method: 'baz'
}

type Model = ModelA | ModelB

const dictionary = {
    a: {
        foo: () => 'foo',
        bar: () => 42
    },
    b: {
        baz: () => 'baz'
    }
}

const withDict = <
    Key extends string,
    SubKey extends string,
    Fn extends (...args: any[]) => any,
    Dict extends Record<Key, Record<SubKey, Fn>>
>(dict: Dict) =>
    <
        Type extends keyof Dict,
        Method extends keyof Dict[Type],
    >({ type, method }: { type: Type, method: Method }) =>
        dict[type][method]

const getMethod = withDict(dictionary)

// () => string
const result = getMethod({ type: 'a', method: 'foo' })

// () => number
const result2 = getMethod({ type: 'a', method: 'bar' })

// expected error
const result3 = getMethod({ type: 'a', method: 'z' })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwIJQLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AIbn6EC2EwAFomeQGZxzlQA%20FAI0oAnGgF9cuYtHhJkAIUw5aBaWwE1CUBs1aDKAL3GTpsRCiWyU6flYWSAxnAB2AZ2BQEASwfAvLkRAlPC1KMhCtQk44MgAKAEpMAD4KaPIAGhVIoWE4xIwUgBYAJiyxTK0BcKzKwzzk-SMy3AlcJzcPAHcvZgARHw8sAB4sgGkIIIgAD2AIZwRXKHdhL2cAcwrCAGUAVwFxyZm5haXgFfXNggAxZyhp2fnF2IA6V5E11zJKZxAAbQBdfIpb4gS5Qfq%20O5HR5QABKECcwgQQwO6ThCLgSKGu32EzRNySSVwSVi3l8ZAhwCBWRGkUIABVwNB7sdFgBrCZwdjggZgrQwRgsBBQh4nDkgLk83y-RmQf5gknYIhMtE6IVQMThZWkKCyiCqwV6AW6YVial0ghk4C-aT-X5qxD-RwudxQNaMY3qrDdPoDUkDfzOQLxSQAelDUASDWWqzWbRdHmEEFcO2QgzdHsNCFiSrUFGoBpNbDSGpDuHDkaBUGcOzoAggwnjHSgSZTaeKSndwE9iBz2ogbAL2iz6hEPDNYYj00gvggwobwkxTddrdTwAAzJ3Mya%203mqBlh0WKEZS0A)

As you might have noticed, I have used currying to infer `dictionary`.

In your case TypeScript was unable to infer `dictiopnary` since it was declared out of function scope.

You can find more examples of function arguments infering in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

**UPDATE**

You can also use this approach:

```js
const withConfig = <Dictionary,>(config: Dictionary) =>
    <Type extends keyof Dictionary,
        Method extends keyof (Dictionary)[Type]
    >(
        type: Type,
        method: Method
    ) => config[type][method]

const applyConfig = withConfig({
    a: {
        foo: () => 'foo',
        bar: () => 42
    },
    b: {
        baz: () => 'baz'
    }
})

applyConfig('a', 'bar') // ok
applyConfig('a', 'baz') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGwIJQLxQN4CgoFSiQBcUA5AIbn6EC2EwAFomeQGZxzlQA%20FAI0oAnGgF9cuYtHhJkAIUw5aBaWwE1CUBs1aDKAL3GTpsRCiWyU6flYUnw0AGqVkAVwgBnADwAVAHxKvgDaANYQIHDsUL4AupIAxnAAdp7AUAgAlgnAmSkiIEp4WpRkxVqEnHBkABQAlJiBHFzkADQqFULCtQ0YgQAsAEwdYu1aAmUd44Y9jfpGI7hiANyJKWlQAO6ZzADCKeyZAOZK3gAi2bn5wiCt-jVJyYdHZBc5eckFvf4dfo5QEAAHsAIMkEJ4oOFItE3ldPjcxhUCDBGCwEADgaDwZCIlEoDVYR8vsFfI54lp7lNCGoYo5EUidGiyCjdAgOt8oI9nsFpLFgozEPFcI8NpQwGBkCB9k9jkptnsDscauUCKVlEiCFVZn0KFU2lSCF1tQNhlpRh0JuqNUIDMb5ppCBIxHVJGKJVLFUcalQ2vpRA0APQBqBwUK4N2S6XPb3UVr2wPBoGQHIQdEQYTCODCSRAA)

Comment: It is a bit unreadable but it guards you before invalid arguments