# Function mixing generic type sources in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a function to can receive 2 generic types, one from the call itself and the other one from the variable.

However, it looks like I can either call it without any type or with 2 types but I cannot mix both techniques.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
const bar: string = "";

const foo = <A,B>(arg: B): B => {
  const sideEffect: A = 0; // Do some stuff here
  return arg;
}

foo(bar); // OK
foo<number>(bar); // FAIL: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
foo<number,string>(bar); // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler can not understand, you can set default type for B.

```js
const bar: string = "";

const foo = <A,B=any>(arg: B): B => {
  const sideEffect: A = 0; // Do some stuff here
  return arg;
}

foo(bar); // OK
foo<number>(bar); // FAIL: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)
foo<number,string>(bar); // OK
```

Comment: please avoid answering with only code example. Try to provide some explanation

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should to consider when you want to write a function in typescript:

- your generic types should be binded with values. In fact, generic parameter is infered type of provided argument. It is unsafe to use generic without values.
  See example:

```js
const foo = <A,>() => {
    const sideEffect: A = 0; // error
    return sideEffect;
}

foo<number & { name: 'John' }>().name // BOOM! Runtime error
```

As you might have noticed, `number & { name: 'John' }` is assignable to constraint `number` but it might lead to unexpected behavior. This is why you have an error here `const sideEffect: A = 0; // error`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187022/why-cant-the-generic-interface-in-ts-infer-the-type-correctly/69188596#69188596) for more explanation and my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#generic_constraints)

Let's reimplement this function:

```js
const bar: string = "";

const foo = <A extends number, B>(arg: B, a: A): B => arg

foo(bar, 0); // OK
foo(bar); // fail, expects two arguments
```

There is one exception of this rule. You may be forced to provide explicit generic parameter if your function expects an array:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [state, handleState] = useState([])

    const stateIsNever = state // never[]
}
```

In order to type `state`, you should provide explicit generic parameter:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [state, handleState] = useState<number[]>([])

    const stateIsNumber = state // number[]
}
```

**SUMMARY**

Each generic parameter should be binded with function argument.

For instance, take a look at `Haskell` or `F#` type systems.

```ml
module Module =
    // val foo : a:'a -> 'a
    let withArg a = a
    // val withoutArg : unit -> unit
    let withoutArg () = ()
```

There is a generic parameter `a` which was automaticaly created for `withArg` function.

Using generics without values it is like to have economic system without gold.

If you still want to use generics without values, like here:

```js
const foo = <A,>() => {
    const sideEffect: A = 0; // error
    return sideEffect;
}
```

you should be aware that it is unsafe and TS system will not help you much to avoid runtime errors.

Even more, you should write your function in a way when you are not required to provide any generics during function call. Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#function_inference) about function argument inference

P.S. Please take a look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130587/avoid-silly-inference-for-union-types-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-bec/69130873#69130873). There are a lot of generics, but you don't neet to provide each generic when you call a function. TS is able to infer each of them