# Typescript returns the union of subtypes, not the indexed subtype itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a complex object containing child elements of different types:

```
const stores = {
    A: {
        dataA: 'something A',
        getDataA(){
            return this.dataA;
        }
    },
    B: {
        dataB: 'something B',
        getDataB(){
            return this.dataB;
        }
    }   
}
```

To get child `A` I do the following:

```
type TStore = typeof stores;

function getStore(key: keyof TStore){
    return stores[key]
}

const child = getStore('A');
```

The problem is I can't reach the properties of this child because it has the following type:

```
const child: {
    dataA: string;
    getDataA(): string;
} | {
    dataB: string;
    getDataB(): string;
}
```

But I expect the child to be of the next type:

```
const child: {
    dataA: string;
    getDataA(): string;
}
```

There is a function that works properly:

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return obj[key];
}
```

but requires an `obj` argument, which is redundant in my case.

So how do I get my `getStore` function to work the same as `getProperty`?

**UPDATE**

In fact, I'm trying to implement some kind of helper function for `MobX` that will retrieve props from combined stores. So, I have a function:

```
const useStores = <T extends object = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(key: K) => {     
     const stores = useContext<T>(StoreContext);     
     return stores[key]; 
}; 

const child = useStores<TStore>('B');
```

But it still returns union of subtypes. The `StoreContext`is a `React.Context` has `any` type because I don't know the type when it is created. So, I need to cast it later.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoApPN) work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to infer `key` argument instead of just providing its type

```js
const stores = {
  A: {
    dataA: 'something A',
    getDataA() {
      return this.dataA;
    }
  },
  B: {
    dataB: 'something B',
    getDataB() {
      return this.dataB;
    }
  }
}

type TStore = typeof stores;

function getStore<Key extends keyof TStore>(key: Key) {
  return stores[key]
}

const child = getStore('A');
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoApPN)

More about type inference on function arguments you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

> What if I need generic function something like this ?

Than you need to `curry` it, just like I did in [my article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes):

```js
const stores = {
  A: {
    dataA: 'something A',
    getDataA() {
      return this.dataA;
    }
  },
  B: {
    dataB: 'something B',
    getDataB() {
      return this.dataB;
    }
  }
}

type TStore = typeof stores;


const withDictionary = <Dict extends Record<string, unknown>>(dict: Dict) =>
  <Key extends keyof Dict>(key: Key) => dict[key]

const getStore = withDictionary(stores)

const child = getStore('A');
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbQ4oN)

Related articles: [curry react components](https://catchts.com/currying-components) , [curry dictionary](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments#second_level_inference)

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130587/avoid-silly-inference-for-union-types-element-implicitly-has-an-any-type-bec/69130873#69130873)

Comment: What if I need a generic function that casts `stores` to a new type?

Comment: @Nolesh what do you mean ? Please provide an example

Comment: @Nolesh could you please update your question with appropriate comments ?

Comment: @Nolesh because your function expects two generics. Since you have provided one explicitly, TS will no longer infer second one, it expects you to provide it also, otherwise it will be a union of `A` | `B`. So you either need to provide both generics explicitly `useStores<TStore,'B'>('B'); ` or  provide extra `context` argument , see [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGAlVN)

Comment: or, if context argument is static (not computed) you can get rid of generic `T` at all. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgQ0lm)

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I updated my question. Please look at it.

Comment: Btw, my function expects two generics, but the last one is set by default. Or does it work differently?

Comment: @Nolesh yes, it expects two, but if you provided one, you need to provide another one. If you did not provide second one, TS will not infer it for you, it just use default value you have provided for second generic